# Highcharts - vertical bar chart with timeline

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

During construction of a vertical bar chart using Highcharts, is there any possibility that we can have TIMELINE in x axis?

Example: Assume my 'series' option is of following format.

```
[{ name : '2015-01-01', :data => [4]},
 { name : '2015-01-02', :data => [5]},
 { name : '2015-01-03', :data => [3]}
 { name : '2015-01-04', :data => [2]}
 { name : '2015-01-05', :data => [1]}
 { name : '2015-01-06', :data => [4]}
 { name : '2015-01-07', :data => [5]}
 { name : '2015-01-08', :data => [5]}
 { name : '2015-02-12', :data => [2]}
 { name : '2015-02-22', :data => [2]}
 { name : '2015-02-24', :data => [1]}]
```

I want highchart something like this

[image: Vertical Bar -Prototype I need]

Is is possible to accomplish the above using Highcharts?

Comment: But above screenshot is using categories, not datetime axis. If you want datetime axis, then your x-values should be as timestamps (in JS timestamps are base on milliseconds).

Comment: Hey JackieChiles! thanks for your reply. I tried sending data as milliseconds also.But, no luck.

Comment: Hi, I think you mean me ;) Anyway, I mean something like this: `data=> [ [timestamp, value], [timestamp-value] ... ]` Or whatever it should look like in your language..

Comment: Hey Pawel! Yeah i tried sending the timestamp as well. I doubt whether highcharts has capability to group the data based on month. Getting my point here?

Comment: Oh, you want group points by month? Then answer is no: Highcharts won't do that for you, so you need to preprocess your data. When using Highstock it would be done easier by [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping).